# How can I call external method at start and end of specific timeline period

Tags: svg.js

I currently have some animation on my timeline and at a specific time, I want to display multiple text elements in my `<div>` container. What I want to achieve is a call to a method without using any other external libraries.

Given following snippet of code:

```
            draw.rect().size(0, 0).opacity(0).timeline(timeline).animate({
                duration: element.duration,
                delay: element.delay,
                when: "now",
            }).queue(
                (time) => handler("before", element, time)
            ).after((time) => handler("after", element, time))
```

I thought about using an invisible element and only receive events when an animation starts and ends. This works fine for `after` callback, but not for `before`. When I try to use `during()` syntax, it gives me each event in the timeline, instead of only one when it starts.

Thought about adding Runner to Timeline, but I don't know how to achieve this neither.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Which part is not working?

Comment: My problem is that initFn is running only once to initialize and queued method is running at each timeline step. When I revert timeline to start, I can't find a way to have a callback exactly when animation is appearing to show one element and hide it when `after` method is called.

I managed to just call my `show` method at each timeline step. This also prevents situation when timeline was moved in time and element would not appear on screen.